# Is there a console command for unlimited ammo?

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive

I'm playing a lot more Classic Comp matches now, and one thing I'd like to practice is getting the hang of weapon recoil and nade placement.

However, if I play on a map by myself, and there are no bots to shoot, I can't get money.  Buying nades and guns are expensive, and I'd love to be able to have unlimited ammo so I can practice popflashes and snade throws, and practice weapon recoil, etc.

Is there any way to do so?

Comment: http://www.gamerconfig.eu/commands/counter-strike-global-offensive/  has `sv_infinite_ammo` listed

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I believe you're looking for the following console command:

```
sv_infinite_ammo 1
```

You can find a really helpful community-contributed list of console commands on the Steam forums [here](http://forums.steampowered.com/forums/showthread.php?t=2637892).

Comment: Do you need `sv_cheats 1` for this to work as well or no?

Comment: works for grenades too

Answer (score 5):

This is late, but a post for anyone googling this question.

To practice nade throws, hit "Play">"Play with Friends", then change the settings to Deathmatch and change it from Public to Private. This will basically make a deathmatch game just for you. You can add friends if you want, but you'll need good internet to keep from them lagging.

When it loads, open console and type in "changelevel de_dust2" (assuming you're practicing for this map as it's the most popular map, if not change the "de_dust2" part)

Then when that loads, type "sv_cheats 1" into console. 
Type "kill" into console for good measure.
Copy and paste this into your console: "bot_kick; sv_infinite_ammo 1; give weapon_hegrenade; give weapon_flashbang; give weapon_smokegrenade; sv_grenade_trajectory 1; sv_showimpacts 1; mp_buy_anywhere 1; mp_buytime 99999; impulse 101" (take out "bot_kick" if you also want to practice shooting)

Finally, type "kill" into console for the effects to take place.

Answer (score 5):

Typing `sv_infinite_ammo 2` will give you unlimited ammo, but you will still have to reload.

Comment: An explanation for the downvote would have been nice, was it downvoted because the answer is wrong? If there IS a difference between sv_infite_ammo 1 and sv_infite_ammo 2 this could be really helpful for practice purposes.

Answer (score -1):

I recommend downloading a map or two that are specifically made to practice recoil control and aiming and take care of this kind of stuff automatically. One that I use is training_aim_csgo, which you can download here: csgo.gamebanana.com/maps/168139

Note the author's comment on how to get it to work, though:

> Write in console "noclip", fly out of the hole and put noclip again ;) or hit whatever key your noclip is bound to. (Default is "V" key)